# utilization of m/m/c queue

Tags: queueing-theory

What is the utilization of m/m/c queue ? in some texts such as [http://www.amazon.com/Queueing-Networks-Markov-Chains-Applications/dp/0471565253](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471565253) 
said: individual server utilization $\rho =(\lambda)/(\mu * c)$.
But, is it the whole system utilization with load independent assumption? 
or it is only  utilization of one server inside whole system?
and is it the load independent utilization what is the load dependent utilization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the formula for utilization is $\rho = \frac{\lambda}{c\mu}$. This describes the proportion of total service capacity being used in the system, so is the whole system utlization. The combined $c$ servers can serve at a maximum rate $c\mu$ and jobs arrive on average at rate $\lambda$, so this value will be less than 1.

The same formulas also describes the proportion of each server's time being used (because the M/M/c model does not keep track of which server is serving which job, only on the number of jobs in the system).

Comment: and i think whole system throughput in load dependent service rate condition is:$\lambda=\Sigma \pi(k)*\mu(k)$  $\pi(k)$ is the probability that k jobs in system  and  $\mu(k)$ is load dependent service rate. and whole system utilization is $\rho=(1/c)*\Sigma (min(k,c)*\pi(k)) $